# Android Studio Compile Error: Could not find runtime-2.4.0.aar

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

When trying to run my application on my android device, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find runtime-2.4.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/2.4.0/runtime-2.4.0.aar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I have tried:

1. Setting my compileSdkVersion and minSdkVersion to 31
2. Checking that the library does indeed exist in the maven repository [here](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0)

**My build.gradle (app level)**

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 31
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.brianokoth.skillsapp"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 31
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
        implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.4.0'
    }
```

**My build.gradle (project level)**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I look forward to any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

first you could try `File -> Sync Project With Gradle Files` just to make sure it has been properly imported. Second it's better to add all the `life cycle dependencies` instead of just one, that's obsolete. so delete the current one and use these one instead:

```
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-alpha02"
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

Comment: I added those dependencies and synced the project with the gradle files but the error still stands.

Comment: delete the old one and use these ones instead

Comment: just tried it. Unfortunately the problem still stands.

Comment: so you deleted the "lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime" dependecy and it still gives a error on it?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: the last resort would be "invalidate cache and restart"

Comment: The issue is still there. I think i'll just create a new project and copy the code over and see if that somehow fixes it. But thanks for the suggestions.